# Quarkus: Why Do I need to specify Kafka sink and sources in application.properties

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus

I've been learning about Quarkus and it is pretty nice. I'm enjoying that it integrates well with other things.

I've been following this guide (https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka) on using Quarkus with Apache Kafka and I got a little miffed at why we need to specify the sink and source "endpoints"? "channels" in the application.properties file. Are these just not a repeat of what's in the code? Maybe I'm not understanding something here, but I thought it would be really nice to not need to configure these.

Also, does that mean if I have a Quarkus app that's speaking to several different topics that I'd need to configure the sync for each of them?

I can't tell if I'm just missing something OR if the guide isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide is correct.

The reason is that the Kafka topic names could be different from the channel name on `@Incoming` or `@Outgoing`.

Some environments might have meaningless names of topics, such as "abcdefg", but you can define the channel name to be "prices".

Also, it means that you can use `@Outgoing` and `@Incoming` in the same application/microservice pointing to the same Kafka topic, but using different channel names in the configuration.